# How to handle data response from payment gateway if the user close his browser before redirect back to merchant site

Tags: payment-gateway

I got a complain from a customer when he buy a product from my website.
He had closed the browser (lost electric or etc ..) before the transaction completed. So, his browser did not redirect back to our website.

Customer card got charged but the order cannot completed because our system did not recieve any response data from payment gateway.

So anyway how can we handle this issue from technical side? I must do manual work (call him and explain everything).
Our payment gateway is MIGS (Visa & Master).

Comment: This is too broad for this site to cover.

Comment: Yes, i understand my question is so general.
But i hope someone can give me some advise at technical side ( a method to avoid this issue ..)

Comment: Unfortunately questions that are this broad are not allowed on this site.   I suggest reading *[What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)** and **[What kinds of question should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)** to get a better understanding of what questions are allowed here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a background job that queries uncompleted transactions from MIGS (IE. Transactions that are not either successful or failed). Once you get the transaction information, you can then complete the order. You can use a tool like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) to setup background jobs

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MIGs has a query endpoint, you can record on your side that the user has an open transaction when you first submit the payment request. If they return to your site later after a problem, you will see that the transaction is still open currently and can submit a query request to MIGS to validate if it has completed and if so release the goods and mark the transaction complete